# Machine schedules in LaTeX (pgfgantt)

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

I would like to know how to represent a Job Shop Schedule using pgfgantt. Usually you find the resources in the left and the tasks align in the same line if they are processed by this specific resource.

[image]

Edit: the answer is to use gant group as bellow:

```
\ganttgroup[inline=false]{$Machine 1$}{0}{1}
    \ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{$Task x$}{13}{14}
    \ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{$Task y$}{16}{19} \\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you edit your question to show a minimal document with what you *have* got working using `pgfgantt`?  Then people will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I already answered it. I will improve the description.

Comment: Please post compilable code rather than just fragments - in both questions and answers. It makes things much easier for people trying to help you or to learn from your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

Bellow you may find a simple example.

```
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
y unit chart=0.5cm,
vgrid,hgrid,
title height=1,
group/.style={draw=none,fill=none},  % remove group borders, etc
inline,                              % draw bars inline
bar/.style={draw,fill=gray},
bar incomplete/.append style={fill=yellow!50},
bar height=0.7]{1}{24}
 \gantttitle{Gantt}{24}  \\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1} \\
 \ganttgroup[inline=false]{$T_{1,1}$}{0}{1}
    \ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=yellow}]{$O_{i,j}$}{13}{14}
    \ganttbar[bar/.style={fill=blue}]{$O_{i,j}$}{16}{19} \\

\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]